# OverFlowException Terminates the program. Should It?

Tags: .net, exception, overflowexception

In our windows service, an OverFlowException occurs (by a third party dll). However, there is a nice try/catch block available and as I know, this should NOT terminate the program and it is handle-able exception as compared to StackOverFlowException which can't be handled and it does cause to terminate the program. Right?

In the event log, I have this

```
    Application: QueuedJobProcessor.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OverflowException
Stack:
   at Syncfusion.CompoundFile.XlsIO.Native.PropVariant.FreeName()
   at Syncfusion.CompoundFile.XlsIO.Native.PropVariant.Finalize()
```

I tried to simulate this by a test application and the OverflowException was caught. I wonder, why it still terminates the service and why it is NOT handled in try/catch block.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the `try/catch` block?

Comment: try/catch block is simple as it should be. Try {code goes here} catch {handling goes here} end try. It is indeed enclosed in several try catch blocks where a parent routine calls a child method and it calls further child and so on. and EVERY routine have its own try catch.